# OpenGL, Isometric 2D Map and Textures

Tags: opengl, textures

In OpenGL I'm drawing a 2D isometric grid. (picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4jHV.png). Please don't mind the sloppy code as a lot of this is just trying things out, I'm trying to get my hands dirty with this stuff before I'll properly write the tiling part of my actual engine.

Each tile is 76 pixels wide and 38 pixels high. Now I want to texture each of the tiles with a  little grass texture that I made. However, that ain't going to well!

My problem is, the texture keeps looking all messed up. It's way smaller than it should be (like half the size), and it's surrounded by white. This is the code I use to apply the texture (which is of 76x38 in size, of course!).

```
void drawSquare(int x, int y) {
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i( 38, -19); glVertex2i(x+38, y);
        glTexCoord2i(-38,  19); glVertex2i(x,    y+19);
        glTexCoord2i( 38, -19); glVertex2i(x-38, y);
        glTexCoord2i(-38,  19); glVertex2i(x,    y-19);
    glEnd();
}
```

This is the part of the code that calculates the X and Y.

```
for (int y = 1; y < gridY+1; y++) {
    for (int x = 1; x < gridX+1; x++) {
        drawSquare((x-y) * 38 + (SCREEN_SIZE_X/2), (x+y) * 19);
    }
}
```

I should probably also add, that I put the settings of my ortho like this.

```
glOrtho(0, SCREEN_SIZE_X, 0, SCREEN_SIZE_Y, -1, 1);
```

(SCREEN_SIZE_X and SCREEN_SIZE_Y just being 800x600)

Anyone that could help me out here? That'd be greatly appreciated. Perhaps to make it more clear, this is how it looks like right now!

EDIT:
After some help it's been changed to this.

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
//glColor3f(r, g, b);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2i(x+38, y);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2i(x,    y+19);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2i(x-38, y);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2i(x,    y-19);
glEnd();
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSSXy.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texture coordinates should go from 0 to 1, not from -38 to 19 when using GL_TEXTURE_2D.

Also, you should use glTexCoord2f() instead.

**Edit:**
This is probably the easiest/best way: just draw the whole texture as a single quad, and enable transparency (blending), just make sure your texture has the corners 100% transparent!

Note: you can still use glTexCoord2i() since you always use the whole texture. But if you are going to make a texture atlas, then glTexCoord2f() is necessary.

```
void drawSquare(int x, int y) {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(x-38, y-19);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(x+38, y-19);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(x+38, y+19);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(x-38, y+19);
    glEnd();
}
```

Remember: Texture coordinates zero point (0,0) is **bottom left**

Also, dont forget to set the blendmode as:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also, make sure you load your texture with the alpha channel, if its still not working, make sure the alpha channel exists in your opengl texture.

Comment: I've tried that, but then the texture still comes out all borked up. I could show you how it looks like in that case.

Comment: did you clamp your texture coordinates between 0 and 1 ? try using only 0 and 1 and see if the texture shows up _completely_ in each tile, if not, then something else is wrong...

Comment: @Jesse, that image looks fine. How it should look like?

Comment: @Jesse, can you post your original texture as one image here. im not sure how youre trying to render this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a shot when I'm back at the computer. That's probably it though. OpenGL been a while for me ago for me, it's all coming back to me! Cheers for your help!

Comment: While it works, my texture ends up looking really, really weird. I'll show you: http://i.imgur.com/CWJGe.png

Comment: @Jesse, i see, you probably want to render the tile exactly as you drew it... Then i think the only way to do that is to enable blending and just draw the whole tile like you did before. that will be slower though, but i think its how such rendering is usually done.

Comment: Yay.. blending, my best friend. *sarcasm* Thank you.

Comment: @Jesse, i added example. edit: you might need to flip the vertex coords in y-axis, since im not sure which render mode you use.

Comment: That's lovely, thank you. That sorted all my problems. You're an angel! Too bad all the help was forfeit though, I've settled on just making a side scrolling shooter for the time being, get myself acquainted with OpenGL again, it's been too long!